# No alternatives to isopropyl alcohol to clean TFT displays?

Tags: cleaning

I'm using pure (99,99%) IPA to clean the surface of small TFT displays (less than 2 inch) to eliminate any trace of dust and (accidental) silicone before mounting them in a sealed slot beneath a small plexiglass window.

I use special paper-wipes (no dust) for the cleaning operation. Nevertheless I'm quite disappointed from the fact that, after evaporation, the isopropyl-alcohol leaves always a visible halo on the surface.
It takes me a lot of time to eliminate such halo by using... the water vapor from my breath. Only in this way I can to definitely clean the surface.

There are no other products leaving zero residuals than the IPA?

Comment: Water, of the distilled variety. Stuff like food and saliva sometimes is soluble in water, but not alcohol.

Comment: Silicone rubber or silicone oil/grease?

Comment: Maybe pure distilled water is the only way to go.
Silicon rubber/oil? Never heard before... is there any cleaning product based on that?
-------
By the way, I saw some videos about companies producing optical lens. The workers were using some kind of cleaning liquid in a small bottle over their desk. The bottle had a little pump on the top, so the worker was pumping on it to spill small quantities of liquid on a paper-wipe.
What kind of product is that? Any Idea?